# Lpc1769 Adc Reading Problem

Tags: adc, frequency, lpc

I am trying to use LPC1769's ADC. The ADC is operating at 12 MHz. In the LPC1769, for one conversion, 65 clock cycles are required. It means that for one conversion, 5.41 us are required. I toggle one pin in ADC IRQ handler. This pin's freq is 57 kHz. It means that one conversion is completed in 17.54 us. First question is why this is happening?

Second question, when I am trying to sample 10 Hz sine wave, it works well. I am reading the ADC value and sending this value to DAC for testing. When the frequency is increased, the peak to peak value is decreased. So what is the problem?

Do you have any advice for these problems?

Comment: If you are *toggling* the pin then its frequency will be half.  If you are triggering the ADC conversion in software there will be some time in between - you would only achieve the full rate by having the ADC in a continuous conversion mode.  Also make sure the clock is what you think it is - there may be a prescaler, and on many devices (not sure if this is one) the divisor is *one more than* the programmed count, ie, "2" means "divide by 3",

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes prescaler exist but divisor is 0. So adc sampling freq is about 100 khz. This is enough for sampling 2 khz sine wave. But ı cant. Peak to peak value of the sine wave at dac Output is so small

Comment: Generally it is best to try to break a big problem like this into pieces.  Look at how you are triggering conversions.  For the voltage vs. frequency, verify the output of your source, and explain your input and output circuits.  Consider graphing the amplitude vs. frequency.  Rather than testing the ADC-DAC path as a whole, consider sampling to data you can check, or else using a calculated data source to drive the DAC.

Comment: I would try using burst mode and continuously monitor the 'done' bit in the status register(s), and toggle an I/O based on that as a starter. Note you should read the results to prevent an overrun flag which may pollute the experiment.

Comment: What are you driving the ADC input with? The input (defined in figure 29 in the datasheet) shows a widely varying parasitic resistance. I note that this varies with voltage (hopefully supply only but there is no detail on this).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

The part contains a successive approximation style ADC, which means that the ADC gets an "answer" one bit at a time.  It places a "1" in the most significant bit of a DAC and compares the output of the DAC to the input signal.  If the input signal is higher than the DAC output, it leaves the "1" in this position.  If the signal is lower, it changes the DAC input to a zero.  Then it repeats this operation on the second-most-significant bit and so forth until all bits are done.

This process depends on the signal being the same amplitude all the way through the conversion.  If the input signal changes during a conversion, the process fails. You can see that it will not be able to convert an appropriate peak value (either positive or negative) unless the signal remains at the peak value throughout a full conversion period.  One possible explanation for your problem may be that at higher frequencies, the input value is changing during the conversion period.  A solution might be to implement a sample and hold at the input.